# clean url for subgroup using .htaccess & PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I convert an url as below :

http://localhost/series/dynamics/admin/cleanURL/value1?subgroup=value2

to a cleaner URL,

for e.g: http://localhost/series/dynamics/admin/cleanURL/value1/value2

I am using $_GET and have the option of using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
The name of the php file is index.php. I have managed to achieve clean url for the first parameter i.e. value1 but clueless on how to do so for value2

My htaccess looks like this, pretty sure it needs to pass a second parameter but not able to work out how.

```
 Rewriteengine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?group=$1
```

I have tried: `^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?group=$1?subgroup=$2` and few other methods but none of them are working

Please have a look at 2 PHP codes below, I am not sure if "&amp" will do the job as anything apart from "?" take me to a different page.

```
<li id="nav"<?php if($pageid==$nav['group']){echo'class="active"';}?>><a href="<?php echo $nav['group'];?>"><?php echo $nav['product']?></a></li>


<a href="?subgroup=<?php echo $list['subgroup']; ?>" <?php if($tst1 == $list['subgroup']){echo 'class="active"';} ?> ><?php echo $list['subgroup']."(".$list['contains'].")".'<br/>';?></a>
```

Can I use "&" instead of "?"  in the link for subgroup ?

Comment: Where are you putting this .htaccess file?

Comment: your rule just matches EVERYTHING and appends it as another query paramter. if you want to strip  off the `subgroup=value2`, then you should be searching for that explicitly.

Comment: @MarcB the problem is that they are both related to each other hence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems I see. Whenever you need to add another parameter you need to add another `capture group` `([a-zA-Z]+)` in the `RewriteRule pattern` or it won't know to look for the in the URI. So using Backreference `$2` without another capture group in the pattern will be empty because you only have one.

Also your query string format is invalid. You only use the `?` once at the beginning and then the ampersand (`&`) to add more key/value pairs.

Something like this is probably what you're after. I changed it a bit to prevent writing the conditions multiple times.

```
 RewriteEngine on

 #if file or directory is real, do nothing
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 #rewrite group and subgroup e.g. http://.../value1/value2/
 Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?group=$1&subgroup=$2 [L]
 #rewrite group e.g. http://.../value1/
 Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?group=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please have a look at 2 PHP codes above, I am not sure if & will do the job as anything apart from ? take me to a different page. Also how do I handle blank space & "-" when I have such values defined for subgroup.